# How to Use PDO MySQL on Eclipse PHP and Run In PHP CLI Application?

Tags: php, eclipse, pdo

Currently I'm using Eclipse PHP IDE and try to using PDO MySQL on this IDE. The code that I'm gonna try is the [PDO constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=db_pdo;host=localhost';
$user = 'imbagila';
$password = 'mypass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

After that, I'm gonna run that code on PHP CLI Application in IDE. But then it's return the error like this :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in
/home/imbagila/Documents/php/eclipse/myproject/index.php:8 Stack trace:
#0 {main}   thrown in /home/imbagila/Documents/php/eclipse/myproject/index.php on line 8
```

But when I tried at terminal (also CLI, by typing `php index.php`) it's return nothing, which mean it's successfully executed with no errors. Why this happens ? Can someone give the solutions so I can use PDO MySQL on my Eclipse IDE ?

- OS : Xubuntu 18.04
- PHP Version : 7.2
- Eclipse PHP IDE Version : Photon Release (4.8.0)
- Eclipse Run Configuration :

  - Runtime PHP : Installed PHP (7.2)
  - Executable path : /usr/bin/php7.2
  - PHP ini file : /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
  - SAPI : CLI Version 7.2.7

Comment: does Eclipse and the terminal use the same PHP? Could you execute `which php` in Eclipse CLI and terminal?

Comment: You load a PDO lib in php.ini? Check this in <?php phpinfo() ?>

Comment: @dogano it's only console, how do i input some script in Eclipse ?

Comment: @AdamWądołkowski it's has PDO as well as PDO MySQL already

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, although I am using a different version of Eclipse.

Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Build id: 2018-09-17-1800

(I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in a Virtualbox on Windows 10.
I expect that is irrelevant.)

OS : Ubuntu 18.04

PHP Version : 7.2

Runtime PHP : Installed PHP (7.2)

Executable path : /usr/bin/php7.2

PHP ini file : /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

After lots of googling, trial and error, and producing several other error messages, I found the following is working for me.

In my /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini, I have these extensions :

```
extension=mysqlnd
extension=pdo
extension=pdo_mysql
```

According to one post I read, the order of these is important.
I haven't tested any other order, since this is working for me.